# Cannot enter in centOS with any user

Tags: shell, shell-script, centos, sudo

I am using **cent OS** Operating system without **GNOME**.

In the starting, it asks

```
localhost login:
Password:
```

It has one user named **service** under group name **service** whose password is also **service**.

I want to enter in OS by this user named **service**.

When I do this, it shows this lines

```
Last Login: Mon Feb 18 16:16:26 on tty1
-bash: /home/service/.bashrc: Permission denied
-bash-3.2$
```

I changed in **/etc/sudoers**, and add **service ALL=(ALL)  ALL**, right below **root ALL=(ALL)  ALL**, but it didn't work.

when I try to switch from root to service, it shows the same error.

**EDITED**

When I run `ls -a -l | grep .bashrc`, it shows

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root   41 Feb 18 11:40 .bashrc -> /home/service/etc/version.symlink/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 service service 124 Feb 15 13:06 .bashrc-moved-1361167832
```

Help me. Looking for your kind response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login as user 'service' seems to be successful. On login, the Bash shell will be loaded, which by default executes ~/.bashrc. But in your case there seems to be something strange with your ~/.bashrc. You also seem to have a file called '.bashrc-moved-1361167832'.

Now I don't know how this happened, but something seems to have moved your original .bashrc away, and replaced it with a link to a file that you can't execute.

I have no idea what has done this and why, but if you want to get rid of it then you could do this as user 'service' in your home dir ~:

```
sudo rm .bashrc
mv .bashrc-moved-1361167832 .bashrc
```

This will first remove the link to this alternative file. And then (I guess) restore the original.

Now try to relogin.

Comment: I remove the `.bashrc-moved-1361167832.sh` because that is useless. Now tell me how to change the ownership, and this is symlink, see the first line of output of `ls.. command`

Comment: What I ment was the following. I guessed that `.bashrc-moved-1361167832.sh` was your original `.bashrc`, until something has renamed it. Thats why I suggested you would restore it. To change ownership you have to use `chown`, but I'm not sure if this will help you. You may try doing `chown service ~/.bashrc` and see if that helps.

Comment: I resolved this problem , by creating .bashrc in service user, then copy content of above file, then remove above file. 

This problem resolved. Thanks a lot for taking time for me.